# Vaadin RegexpValidator multiple error message

Tags: regex, vaadin, customvalidator

Is it possible to return conditional error message for a vaadin validator?

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
String regex = "?:(foo|bar)";
textField.addValidator(new RegexpValidator(regex, true, getErrorMessage()));
```

I want to have a different error message depending on what the user write in the textField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. One should just override the getErrorMessage of the validator

```
textField.addValidator(new RegexpValidator(regex, true, "") {   
        @Override
        public String getErrorMessage() {
             return setMessage();
        }
});
```